# Why does Blender keep creating keys in the dopesheet while Im modeling?

Tags: modeling

I kept having this issue where when I loaded a save file and the objects had been moved/rotated. I checked the forums and someone said it's because of animation keys in the dope sheet. I never made these keys but they were there. Problem solved except every time I model and I check the dope sheet there's more keys! I'm not creating any keys (consciously anyway) and I already tried turning off most hotkeys that were associated with making keys but it' still happening. If you know of any way of disabling this 'feature' then please, for the love of god let me know. It's driving me nuts!!

TIA,

Martin

Comment: Do you have auto-keying  enabled? Circle button left of the play animation buttons at the bottom of the Timeline Panel (Shift+F12)

Comment: Yes! Thank you , thank you, thank you. Love Blender but I wish the manual was a bit better documented :) Anyway, problem solved hopefully.

Answer (score 3):

Turn off the Auto Keying option in the Timeline panel. The Timeline panel can be opened with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>.

[image]